# Multi Page Application with webpack

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

How to use webpack with `Multi Page Application` , eg, my app is consist of several **business modules**, and each **business module** contains tens of `page`, each `page` has one `entry`. And new pages are created each month, and this lead to the final **hundreds of pages**. so my question is, how do webpack users handle this situation ?

Or `webpack` is just not suitable for `MPA` with hundreds of pages

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for posting 5 months later, but I think I have a Webpack based boilerplace that can handle multiple page application.

I am not sure about the scope of your application and about your understanding of multiple page application its dependency management.

My boilerplate can be found on GitHub (https://github.com/scriptex/webpack-mpa) and consists of:

- Webpack for assets/css/js management
- SCSS as primary CSS preprocessor
- PostCSS as primary CSS postprocessor - handles adding of automatic vendor prefixes, assets loading from `node_modules`, importing of non-scss files, etc
- Latest EcmaScript support thanks to Babel
- PNG Sprites support
- SVG Sprites support
- Minification for production
- Automatic browser reload during development thanks to BrowserSync
- Predefined minimal php files structure
- Ability to make it a Progressive Web App (via another module I created)
- and more.

Once again, I am not sure about the scope of your project, but this boilerplate helps me with my multipage applications and I even use it in my WordPress themes development.